# Copying GIS info from one PDF to another

Tags: gdal, pdf, geospatial-pdf

I can see if a PDF has GIS info attached to it by doing `gdalinfo filename.pdf` but is there a way to copy that info from one PDF to another PDF?

With GeoTIFF's you can do this:

```
listgeo -no_norm old.tif > orig.geo
geotifcp -g orig.geo new.tif new-geo.tif
```

Based on the name, alone, I'm assuming `geotifcp` wouldn't work on PDFs but, based solely on the command names, it's not immediately obvious that `listgeo` wouldn't work on PDFs, so I tried it and got this error:

```
filename.pdf: Not a TIFF or MDI file, bad magic number 20517 (0x5025).
failure in listgeo
```

So I guess `listgeo` doesn't work on PDFs...

I'd prefer it if the method used the GDAL tool suit but if there's a technique that doesn't involve that method that'd be interesting to know, as well.

Comment: listgeo and geotifcp are GeoTIFF utilities ~ https://github.com/OSGeo/libgeotiff